# PHP fopen/fwrite problem on IIS7

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am running PHP5 on IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2. Check out the below code which writes a string received via a POST request parameter into an XML file.

```
<?php
$temp = "";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
    if($_POST["operation"]=="saveLevels"){
        $fileHandle = fopen("c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\test\\xml\\levels.xml", 'w');
        fwrite($fileHandle, stripslashes($_POST["xmlString"]));
        fclose($fileHandle);
        $temp = "success";
    }elseif($_POST["operation"]=="saveRules"){
        $fileHandle = fopen("c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\test\\xml\\rules.xml", 'w');
        fwrite($fileHandle, stripslashes($_POST["xmlString"]));
        fclose($fileHandle);
        $temp = "success";
    }
}
```

When I make a POST request to invoke this code, the application pool owning/hosting the site containing php files, stops (due to some fatal errors, as it writes in event viewer) and then IIS keeps responding with HTTP503 after that. Now, I have given proper permissions to IUSR and IISUSRS on that (test/xml) directory. Those two XML files are not already existing, I have also tried the code when an XML file is already present but; it behaved the same way.
What's wrong with that php code? I have tried it on a linux-box and it behaved as expected.

edit: I have tried various different versions of this code and came up with this result: the fopen call when awaken by a POST request, allways returns FALSE or sometimes NULL, and causes the Application Pool of itself to stop. The exact same code, works OK with a GET request, with exact same parameters. So; I dont know what the problem is but; for the time I'm just going to use GET requests for this operation.

Comment: what are those fatal errors that you mentioned?

Comment: I dont know. In the event viewer, it just says it had to auto-disable Windows Application Pool Service because of a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you var_dump( $fileHandle) for both options, to show us what it has. I notice you're just assuming the file is opened, rather than checking the value (if it's FALSE the fwrite will fail)